# configure apache to send all requests to tomcat

Tags: apache, .htaccess, tomcat

My Spring app deployed to prod server (shared tomcat 5.5) would respond to all URL calls with 404 error (except /). After 3 days of hard work, I found that:

> The problem is that in the production environment tomcat is being
>   fronted by an apache httpd which does not forward requests to tomcat
>   for urls of the form /foobar (without an extension). Apache doesn't
>   know how to deal with those URLs and tries to serve them as static
>   files from the disk.

So, I need to configure apache to send all requests to tomcat. I believe, that would require changes to .htaccess files. I have .htaccess files in the below locations:

```
/public_html/.htaccess
/public_html/WEB-INF/.htaccess
```

Please help me with .htaccess content to achieve desired objective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should configure your [`<Location>`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#location) directive for the URLs that represent your Tomcat application directly in your `httpd.conf` configuration file -- or a corresponding file that is included in a manner that fits in with your distribution (or local environment) configuration. (Look for the [`include` lines](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#include) in your main Apache configuration file if you're not sure whether or not your distribution or local environment is using some mechanism to break apart a configuration file.)

If you place the `<Location>` directive for your Tomcat install in an `.htaccess` file, that file will be re-loaded and re-parsed on every single request, which can have a performance impact. If you place it in the main configuration, it'll be read and parsed once, at server startup (and each time you use the `apachectl` `restart` option to reload the configuration).